# How to setup a Ubuntu custom shortcut for "goto selection"

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

On Windows, I set up a Autohotkey shortcut in a way that the selected text was sent to the OS for execution. If it's a http hyperlink, default browser is launched. If it's a file path, file explorer is launched (the OS figured this out all by itself).

I switched to Ubuntu recently (and I think it's great!) but boy do I miss that shortcut. Before delving into [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/), which seems like a neat tool, I'd like to know if there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll require more details on what explicitly this shortcut/script did so that we might advise how to replicate it for Ubuntu.